# How to match a string in a CSV file and delete the lines before the matched string using Shell scripting

Tags: shell, csv, format, using

My input file is a CSV as below:

```
AOD,10:40:00.128820,11:00:00.128820,19:00:00.000000,19:00:00.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N
AOD,10:45:00.128820,11:00:00.128820,19:00:00.000000,19:00:00.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N

AOD,11:00:00.128820,11:00:00.128820,19:00:00.000000,19:00:00.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N
AOD,11:00:02.128831,11:00:00.128831,19:00:00.000000,19:00:00.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N
AOD,11:00:03.128842,11:00:00.128842,19:00:00.000000,19:00:00.000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N
```

I only need the lines starting at a start_time 11:00:00 and after. I have to delete the lines before 11:00:00. Also I have a endtime say 11:00:01. I need to delete the lines after 11:00:01. How can I do this?

Comment: why not just `grep ',11:00:00\.' file > newFile`? Good luck.

Comment: which column are you looking at? There are 11:00 in both column 2 and 4

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

`cat data.txt | grep 'AOD,11:[0-9][0-9]\:[0][0]'  > result.csv`

;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking at the 2nd  column

```
awk -F, -v start="11:00:00" -v stop="11:00:01" 'start <= $2 && $2 <= stop'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^[^,]*,11:00:00/,/^[^,]*,11:00:01/p'
```